# Simpy: Yielding resource without losing position in queue

Tags: python, simpy

I am very new to Simpy, so I'm looking at writing what should be a simple example:  the expected behavior of drivers at a 4-way stop in the United States.  For those of you not familiar with US driving laws, the basic rule is simple:  the first driver to the intersection, after stopping, has the right of way.  The trick comes when more than one driver arrives simultaneously.  Some rules for simultaneous arrival are obvious (if two drivers arrive and a facing each other and are going straight, both can proceed); others less so (if the two drivers are crossing each other, the one on the right has the right of way).

I'm looking at modeling the intersection as a simple resource with the driver objects queuing for access.  When a driver object is activated, it will look at the other objects in the queue with the same timestamp and apply the rules described above.  If it "has right of way," it will advance the clock and then release the resource, and the next driver object will be activated.  If it does not have right of way, it will still release the resource to the next driver object, but the clock is not advanced.  The important thing in this case is that the first driver needs to remain at the head of the queue.

How might I implement this last part?  Consider this situation.  Three driver objects are created with the same timestamp, one each for entering from the north, east, and south.  Let's say that the east object is the first to be activated.  By the rules, it needs to relinquish the intersection and let the north object go first.  However, once the north object advances the clock and relinquishes the intersection, it should go back to the east, and not the south.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Do you have some code you can show? I would expect that you can just use the `yield simpy.Environment.timeout(0)` dependant on if you want to order your cars by event processing time instead of arrival time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to design the code such that every road is one resource(n=1) with own queues. All cars pass through their respective resources (get -> release) unless one of the other resources is occupied (a simultaneous arrival). If so you can have a form of matrix base that determines what rule applies and if (physical) yielding is appropriate. You can then have the prioritized vehicle move first (with time stamp)

The advantage of the separate queues is that regardless of what car goes when, all lanes will adhere to the FIFO (first-in-first-out) policy of their queue, which is exactly what happens on a real intersection.